# How to bind with service "com.google.android.music.playback.MusicPlaybackService"?

Tags: android, android-music-player

Is it possible to bind with service "com.google.android.music.playback.MusicPlaybackService"

After searching and trying everything i can think of, i was not able to bind with the service. `com.google.android.music.playback.MusicPlaybackService`. I followed all the binding option mentioned on page [how-can-i-start-the-musicplaybackservice-from-an-external-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10250037/how-can-i-start-the-musicplaybackservice-from-an-external-app),but it throws `securityException` as mentioned on the page.I checked that the service `com.google.android.music.playback.MusicPlaybackService` is running on the device.

My requirement is to bind with the service `com.google.android.music.playback.MusicPlaybackService` and control the media playback from another application running in background. Using broadcast Intent i can control the playback as mentioned in the #1 option on the page mentioned above, but using this method i am not able to play a particular song in the default PlayMusic application.

Comment: I know this is "really" old but did you find a solution for that? Tx